# java null manual exception handling

Tags: java, null

I have this static method of the class Plane which returns an object from some int id:

```
private static ArrayList<Plane>Planes = new ArrayList<Plane>();

public static Plane getPlane(int id) 
{
Plane p = null;

int i=0;

while(i<=Planes.size()) 
{
    if(Planes.get(i).getid()==id) 
    {
        p = Planes.get(i);
        
        break;
        
    }
    
    i++;
}`
return p;

}
```

And I have this code which I want to manually throw an exception when the Plane object is null and print Plane doesnt exist!:

```
try 
{
    Plane planetofly = Plane.getPlane(pid);
    
    if(planetofly==null) 
    {
        throw new Exception("Plane doesnt exist!");
        
    }
    
    this.planetofly = planetofly;
    
}
catch(Exception e) 
{
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    
}
```

but instead of getting "Plane doesnt exist at the output" when the plane with that id doesnt exist i get output the message from the IndexOutofBounds Exception.What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if your question is about java, ***why*** did you tag c#?

Comment: because java and c# are very similar to each other

Comment: no. they may share similar syntax at some points, but that's the end of it. they are fundamentally different languages with fundamentally different frameworks. what you're saying is like saying a sportscar is like a tractor because they have four wheels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index out of bounds means that you are trying to access an index in your array which does not exist.

This line is the problem.

```
while(i<=Planes.size())
```

The index starts at zero and ends at Size - 1, so you have to check for less than, not less than or equal to.  Like this:

```
while(i < Planes.size())
```

Comment: @Jun Seo-he This is the immediate solution to your issue. However, I suggest you have a look at Map interface (specifically Map<String, Plane>), you can have all the code in your Plane class reduced to one line of code.